# Show that $\overline A\cap B=A\cap \overline B=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

***Definition***

Let $\left(X,d\right)$be a metric space,and let$Y$ be a subset of$X$.A subset $E$ of $Y$ is **relatively open** in $Y$ if and only if there is an open subset $U$ in $X$ with $E=U\cap Y.$

---

Let $S,A,B$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.$A$ and $B$ are nonempty,relatively open in $S,S=A\cup B$,and $A\cap B=\emptyset $.Do we have $\overline A\cap B=A\cap \overline B=\emptyset?$

$e.g.$If let $S=\mathbb{Q},A=(-\infty,\sqrt{3}),B=(\sqrt{3},+\infty)$,then we have $\overline A\cap B=A\cap \overline B=\emptyset$.In general cases,is this also true?

Comment: No. That intersection is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @sinbadh:Sorry,I reedit it .$A=(-\infty,\sqrt{3}),B=(\sqrt{3},+\infty).$

Comment: Consider a point $b$ in $B$. As $B$ is open everything closely around $b$ is in $B$ and thus not in $A$. Therefore $b$ is not in the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is off, because $A$ and $B$ are not relatively open in $\mathbb{Q}$. $A$ and $B$ are not even subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

What you should have said: $A = (-\infty, \sqrt{3}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, $B = (\sqrt{3}, +\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. These are relatively open in $\mathbb{Q}$ according to your definition (as the open segments are open subsets of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}$). Also $\mathbb{Q} = A \cup B$, as $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ because the open segments are already disjoint in $\mathbb{R}$, so certainly their intersection with $\mathbb{Q}$ also is.

And indeed $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset = \overline{A} \cap B$. In your example this already holds for the open segments, so it's true regardless of whether we take the closure in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. In general this will hold only for the closures taken in the subset, here $\mathbb{Q}$.

So suppose $Y = A \cup B$, $Y \subseteq X$, $A$ and $B$ relatively open, so $A = U \cap Y$, $B = V \cap Y$, where $U,V$ are open in $X$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

If $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$, where the closure is taken in $Y$ (!), then as $B$ is open in $Y$, and contains $x$, $B$ must intersect $A$ and this cannot be. Similarly $A \cap \overline{B}$ is empty, when the closure is taken in $Y$.

When the closure is taken in $X$, the intersection can be non-empty (but then contains points of $X \setminus Y$ of course). I'm not sure whether this can happen in the reals (the ordered structure is quite restrictive), but look for examples in the plane, e.g.